# Axios post not working on React Native but works on PostMan

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, postman, razorpay

I have been using axios for post request, but when i do the post request in postman it works perfectly but when i do post request my react native component it shows error with invalid api key. But all the api keys are correct. I am using this for an payment gateway.

This, payment gateway(razorpay) gives a api key and secret. I am using it correctly, but for some reason i am getting unauthorized access.

Here is my code using axios:

```
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
    .then((data) => {
        var key = 'rzp_test';
        var key_sec = 'Oumh';
axios.post(`https://${key}:${key_sec}@api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_BiG0BeVURQkxKU/capture`, {amount: 1200})
.then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
        alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
    })
.catch((error) => {
        alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
    });
```

Kindly guide me to crack this. When i paste the exact url into postman by replacing $key and $key_sec with original key's , i am getting positive output. But couldn't achieve this using axios in react native

Comment: it looks like you are alerting the data at the wrong place. if you alert the data in `console.log(data)` of success of axios post, you should get the data.

Comment: No , actually the alert is for the parent async function. The expected results is expected from the second .then function

Answer (score 0):

When cross-domain, axios will first send a `options` request to verify that it can pass. You may need to remove the `options` request and send the `post` request directly.